# apache-camel error handler scope clarification

Tags: java, apache-camel

Below is an example route take from Camel In Action book. There is one error handler at context scope and two route definitions. My questions

1. Is it correct to say that the context level error handler is applicable only for Route 1?
2. Does the dead letter error handler kick in for any exceptions thrown from any of the steps in route 2. i.e. from `orderService.validate()` and `orderService.enrich()`.
3. What if I want different error handler for exceptions that arise from `validate()` and `enrich()` methods?

   //context scope error handler

   ```
   errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler()
       .maximumRedeliveries(2)
       .redeliveryDelay(1000)
       .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN));

   //Route 1

   from("file://target/orders?delay=10000")
       .beanRef("orderService", "toCsv")
       .to("mock:file")
       .to("seda:queue.inbox");

   //Route 2 with route scope error handler

   from("seda:queue.inbox")
       .errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("log:DLC")
       .maximumRedeliveries(5).retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.INFO)
       .redeliveryDelay(250).backOffMultiplier(2))
       .beanRef("orderService", "validate")
       .beanRef("orderService", "enrich")
       .to("mock:queue.order");
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your assumptions on #1 & #2 are correct...

for #3, either define [Exception Clauses](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html) to catch explicit exceptions thrown by your bean methods (OrderValidateException, EnrichException, etc.) or use inline [try-catch](http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html) blocks around each step in your route (I prefer the first approach myself)